# ¿Por qué en "SOLID" la D *NO* es inyección de Dependencias?

Tags: inyeccion-de-dependencias, design

A veces crea confusión la diferencia entre *Inyección de Dependencias* e *Inversión del Control*; en los principios *SOLID* este principio es la letra "D" luego ¿por qué no es inyección de **D**ependencias?

Answer (score 1):

La confusión viene de la forma de traducir el término original.

La **D** en *SOLID* es el *Dependency Inversion Principle* que es esa letra **D** pero en castellano se viene a usar *Principio de Inversión del Control*.

Es común confundirse y pensar que la citada **D** es por *Inyección de Dependencias*. Pero todo queda más claro cuando nos percatamos de que la citada *Inyección de Dependencias* no es un principio.

> La Inyección de Depencias es una forma de aplicar el Principio de
>   Inversión del Control.

No es la única: una factoría, o un ServiceLocator también persiguen este principio de diseño.

El Principio de Inversión del Control (o si lo preferimos Principio de Inversión de Dependencias) viene a decir que las implementaciones de niveles superiores no pueden depender de los detalles de los niveles inferiores, deben acceder a los detalles a través de abstracciones (interfaces).

La factoría, el ServiceLocator o el motor de Inyección de Dependencias es un componente de nivel superior que controla y se hace responsable "colocar" las implementaciones exactas donde los elementos indican un interfaz.

De hecho el nombre del principio (*Inversión*) viene dado porqué este flujo de control (desde un componente de alto nivel) es inverso al flujo (sentido) de las dependencias.

Ref: Clean Architecture (Robert C. Martin)

Answer (score 1):

"Alto nivel" y "bajo nivel" son términos asociados con la [inversión de dependencia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) que tiene relación con la inyección de dependencia pero es un concepto diferente. Ambos tienen las iniciales `"DI"`, y `"D"` en ambos significa `"dependencia"`, por lo que pueden crear cierta confusión.

(Lo pienso de esta manera: la inyección de dependencia es una forma de implementar la inversión de dependencia).

Pero en mi opinión, la terminología utilizada al definir la inversión de dependencia puede ser realmente confusa para los programadores de .NET que intentan comprender el concepto. Es aplicable, pero parte de la terminología no se usa entre los desarrolladores de .NET.

De la definición de Robert Martin, citada en Wikipedia,

> Los módulos de alto nivel no deben depender de módulos de bajo nivel. Ambos deberían depender de abstracciones. Las abstracciones no deben depender de los detalles. Los detalles deben depender de las abstracciones.

¿Qué es un "módulo de alto nivel" y un "módulo de bajo nivel"? Si te parece confuso, no estás solo. Realmente no usamos esos términos. La parte que realmente podemos entender y aplicar es que debemos depender de las abstracciones .

En el caso de `MatchResult`, si es solo un contenedor para algunas propiedades, entonces es probablemente lo suficientemente abstracto. Los DTO han sido una práctica común durante algún tiempo, por lo que si el tiempo hubiera revelado que necesitábamos envolverlos en interfaces, ese patrón ya habría surgido. No duele, pero generalmente no es necesario.

Volviendo a la inversión de dependencia, la verdadera confusión proviene del nombre mismo. ¿Qué se está invirtiendo? Cuando vea diagramas como lo que está en la página de Wikipedia, mi recomendación es apartar la mirada de los diagramas cegadores.

[Martin explica](http://web.archive.org/web/20110714224327/http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/dip.pdf) su uso de la palabra "inversión" de esta manera (volviendo a su artículo original sobre el tema)

> Uno podría preguntarse por qué uso la palabra "inversión". Francamente, **es porque los métodos de desarrollo de software más tradicionales**, como el Análisis estructurado y Diseño, **tienden a crear estructuras de software en las que los módulos de alto nivel dependen de módulos de bajo nivel, y en los que las abstracciones dependen de los detalles**. De hecho, uno de los objetivos de estos métodos es definir la jerarquía de subprogramas que describe cómo los módulos de alto nivel realizan llamadas a los módulos de bajo nivel. La Figura 1 es un buen ejemplo de dicha jerarquía. **Por lo tanto, la estructura de dependencia de un programa orientado a objetos bien diseñado se "invierte" con respecto a la estructura de dependencia que normalmente resulta de los métodos de procedimiento tradicionales.**

En otras palabras, la inversión es un contraste entre la aplicación de inversión de dependencia y el estilo "tradicional" de no aplicar la inversión de dependencia. Eso podría ser más claro si proviene de un entorno en el que los "módulos de alto nivel dependen de módulos de bajo nivel" (y utiliza el término "módulo"). Pero si eso no era previamente su "tradición", ¿qué es usted? '¿Invertir?' Nada.

Todos esos detalles todavía tienen significado, pero son extremadamente confusos cuando intentas aprender estos conceptos por primera vez. Mi sugerencia es aplicar esta parte, como ya eres: depende de las abstracciones.

Si lo hace, está aplicando el principio porque, sean cuales sean los "módulos de alto nivel" y los "módulos de bajo nivel", sus clases no dependerán demasiado de otras clases: de alto nivel, bajo nivel o de otro modo.

> Fuente: [Confundido con SOLID e Inyección de Dependencia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38457945/8933039)